# Help to enqueue a js functions ( jquery)

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I have [this js function](http://jsfiddle.net/UqY2C/) (the `textualizer.js` is external) but I can't make it works on WordPress. Any help?

I already added

```
wp_register_script( 'textualizer', WP_THEME_URL . '/assets/js/textualizer.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'textualizer' );
```

to theme functions.

What am I doing wrong? I know it's probably simple, but I can't figure it out.

EDIT: i changed the function in functions.php, a user in irc channel told me that i was missing the correct action hook. still doesn't work...
http://pastebin.com/L8ZRSvzU

Comment: Where are you calling this code? Does a script link get output in the rendered source? (Side note: use **`get_template_directory_uri()` ** rather than `WP_THEME_URL`.)

Comment: You can see it in the pastebin in EDIT. I put the function in functions.php, then i use it in a template page.

the console in the developer tool give me the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (j,s){return new b.fn.init(j,s)} has no method 'Deferred'
and it links me to the plugin file, that should work.

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. Your problem is that you're **deregistering core jQuery and registering an older version**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Google with the error message you posted in your comment, Google show me this: The [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, introduced in jQuery **1.5**

Your source code says, that you use jQuery **1.4.4**.

jQuery is bundled with WordPress and it's version is **1.8.3**. Please use the bundled jQuery and not one from an CDN.

Comment: Yep; this is the problem: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>`. Where do you **deregister core jQuery and register jQuery 1.4.4**? Wherever it is, get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks again.
yeah, i figured out, but I'm using the jQuery bundled with WP.

I use the lib with '<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>' in the header, and in my template i just use get_header. So, where the plugin is using jQuery 1.4.4. ? some way to know? ( firebug? ) I'm still new to this.

Answer (score 2):

`textualizer()` is a jQuery plugin, so you should set a dependency to jQuery

```
wp_register_script(
  'textualizer',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/textualizer.js',
  array( 'jquery' ),
  false, // no version
  true // load into footer
);
```

Even if you load jQuery first, the dependency make sure the jQuery plugin is loaded *after* jQuery.

And it is always a good idea to use a console like Firebug in FireFox or the build in developer tools in Chrome. The console list javascript errors which are very important informations.

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work. you were right, so i made some change:

http://pastebin.com/V6q6s0EJ

Javascript console give me the error:

TypeError: b.Deferred is not a function.
 
The page I'm talking about:
http://www.glenlasio.com/statement/

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure where WP_THEME_URL links to, but here is an idea. Depending on whether you're calling the file of a child or parent theme, you must use the accurate path.

For Example, if you want to refference the parent directory use `get_template_directory_uri()` which is always going to look inside the parent directory.

Or if you want to specify that the file is in the child theme use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, which is gonna fallback to the parent if the child file does not exsist.

Just replace WP_THEME_URL and see if that helps.

Comment: done it, still doesn't work. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Everythings works fine. The problem was the library too old. Thanks to everyone!